# Grey "closed as..." box not showing up on page update

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, live-refresh

I voted to close a question, and then the grey box appeared above the question saying that it has been edited.

I clicked on that, and i got the following image

[image]

as you can see, the button to reopen is present, but the grey box that would normally be below the question telling you  that it was closed was not present.

after refreshing the page with the browser the grey box was there

Comment: A link to said question would be helpful.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha i believe that it's been deleted, but here's the link where It would have been at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485842/set-up-my-own-webserver#15485842

Comment: I think that the AJAX only refereshes the post div itself, not the comments or anything else below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question status blocks will now be refreshed when loading an edit.